# How to save NSDictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, xcode, nsdictionary

Could you tell me please, how can I make something like this:

For example I have an app which contains info about your pets. But firstly, you should add a pet to a database. In a special view, you enter your pet's name, age, breed, color and etc (keys) and then you save it. Here we are, now you have your first pet in the app. But then you wanna add new pets...

**How can I save all these dictionaries with same keys ?** You don't know how may dictionaries to create because you don't know how many pets an user wanna add in the app. What is the easiest way?

What if user wants to add like thousands of pets in the app ? I am sure, I shouldn't create thousands of dictionaries in the code for every possible animal. But how do I do that ?
Like dictionary1 for Deisy, dictionary2 for Bruno, dictionary3 for Hamlet and etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rough description of how it could work:

Somewhere you need to define a collection to hold that pets.

```
NSMutableSet *myPets = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

When the user has entered the data and presses the save button, some method is called in your view controller. Within that method you collect the data, like this:

```
NSDictionary *pet = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nameField.text, @"name", breedField.text,@"breed", nil];
[myPets addObject:pet];
```

At this point the `pet` has been put into the `myPets` `NSMutableSet` and the compiler will release it, so it doesn't exist anymore. The next time the user enters data and presses the button again, a new `pet` will be created and put into `myPets`. Don't worry about millions of instances being created, the compiler will take care of it.

If you want to retrieve individual pets afterwards, you can do something like this

```
for (NSDictionary *aPet in myPets) {
   if ([[aPet objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Lassie"]) {
      // do what you want to do with Lassie
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but I never know how many dictionaries to create like somePet and someOtherPet. I mean, user adds a new pet (a new dictionary) but what will be the name of this dictionary, so I'll be able to save it to a NSMutableSet ?

Comment: @SmartTree if that's really your question, you should be doing more basic things.

Comment: @SmartTree, I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SmartTree, I amended my answer again.

Comment: And last question: doesn't that mean that `myPets` will contain dictionaries with the same name like pet, pet, pet, pet end etc. How do I know where is the one I need ?

Comment: The names of the dictionaries will be gone, you will have to find the pets based on the data the user entered, like the name of the pet. This is what I describe in the last paragraph.

Comment: Right, got it. Thank you Stefan, you opened my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `NSArray` to hold the `NSDictionaries`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I create NSDictionary for every pet ? I mean, user can add thousands of pets, and I am sure I shouldn't make thousands of dictionaries in the code. Thanks !

Comment: Actually, you should be storing this in CoreData.  Use a dictionary only as a "holding object" for the data you need to story about a pet.  Then when the user "saves" or some other event happens that causes a "save", commit that dictionary to a CoreData entity.  When you need to present the user with a list of pets to choose from, you would pull an NSArray out of that CoreData model (or you could use an NSFetchedResultsController).